# CSS3 animation ease-in-out infinite

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    to {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
    }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes zoom {
   from {
        transform: scale(1,1);
   }
   to {
        transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
   }
}


img {
    -webkit-animation: zoom 1s ease-in-out infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: zoom 1s ease-in-out infinite;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<img alt="" src="http://watchingtheworldcup.com/photos/worldcup1.jpg" />
```

I am trying to make the image zoom in and out forever, instead it zooms in and jumps back to the original size.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution ("alternate" property):

```css
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}

@keyframes zoom {
   from {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
   }
   to {
       transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
   }
}


img {
    -webkit-animation: zoom 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: zoom 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img alt="" src="http://watchingtheworldcup.com/photos/worldcup1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes zoom {
    from {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}


img {
    -webkit-animation: zoom 1s ease-in-out infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: zoom 1s ease-in-out infinite;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img alt="" src="http://watchingtheworldcup.com/photos/worldcup1.jpg" />
```

Comment: Dmitriy's solution is better, but I'll keep this here as a demonstration of multiple keyframes.